# Why are my bitizens staying at home?

Tags: tiny-tower

My shop ran out of stock and 2 of the 3 employees went home. I have since restocked the shop but the employees are still at home. How can I get them back to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bitizen's location within the tower is not representative of what they are doing.  If a bitizen has a job, they are always at work.  Do not worry that they don't appear on that floor at any given moment.

Watch the inventories.  You'll notice that they are all still going down (at least... they should be).

Answer (score 1):

If a bitizen "goes home" and you want to force him back to the floor he works on select the bitizen then job->no job. Then reassign him to his original job and it will put him back on the floor where he works. As long ad you don't close the game he should stay there.